# postgresql - a local replication entry doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, backup, pg-hba.conf, pg-basebackup

Maybe it's just too early in the morning, but I can't seem to get pg_basebackup working for a local user. This is part of testing for an hourly backup automated script. I added a line to pg_hba.conf for this and it looks like:

```
local     replication      postgres                      trust
```

But, this entry causes a FATAL error: no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "[local]", user "postgres", SSL off. What did I screw up? I'll be changing the user once I get this part working. The pg_basebackup command looks like:

```
pg_basebackup -D - -Ft -z -c fast -l hourly.backup > backup_file.gz
```

FYI, if I add "-h ", it does work as I do have another pg_hba.conf entry for:

```
host    replication   postgres   10.10.1.129       md5
```

Does local not work for replication entries?

(Using PostgreSQL 9.3)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is: "localhost" can be UNIX sockets, IPv4 or IPv6. The first rule you passed is for UNIX sockets. Try to add a rule for IPv4 and one for IPv6. It should work then. 
Btw, a SIGHUP is enough in case you change pg_hba.conf.

Comment: Unix domain sockets are refered to with `local` and never `localhost`. Anyway the question never mentions `localhost` in the first place, so it's not obvious why it would even be involved here.